# Flutter: Read File fails at the first time but works after Hot reload

Tags: flutter, file, null, state

I try to read a file where i have stored data and to show it on my screen. When I load my App for the first time i get the error shown bellow. After a hot reload my information will be displayed without any error. Do you know why this happens and how I can ensure that my data will be loaded already at the first time?

Maybe it has something to do with calling the state but I don't know.
It is the code at the bottom which causes the problem:

> child: Text(context.select((FileController controller) =>
> controller.text!)),

[image: Error after first load]
[image: Everything works after hot reloading]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:habit_changer/file-handling/file_controller.dart';
import 'package:habit_changer/main/AddHabitDialog.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../utils/Constants.dart';
import 'MainBody.dart';
import 'nav_bar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => FileController())],
    child: MaterialApp(home: MyApp())
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<FileController>().readText();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Habits'),
        backgroundColor: Constants.appBarColor,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            openNavBar();
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.menu, // add custom icons also
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      AddHabitDialog().buildPopupDialog(context),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Text(context.select((FileController controller) => controller.text!)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MyApp file:///C:/Projekte/Flutter%20Projects/habit_changer/lib/main/main.dart:13:30
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:habit_changer/main/main.dart:52:82)
#1      SelectContext.select (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:283:32)
#2      MyApp.build (package:habit_changer/main/main.dart:52:29)
#3      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4648:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when your variable is null initially but then receives the value later on. Change the operator to a null check operator:

```
controller.text ?? ''
```

This will solve the null exception that you are receiving.

Comment: It works now. When I start the App my content is shown immediatly and I dont have to reload the app. But this is actually very confusing: Before, it failed because the field was null. And adding a null check should only lead to empty text and not that the text is already shown at the first time :D?!

Comment: Yes, even though it seems immediate, if it's not available during execution, it will throw an exception :)

Comment: Also, please mark the response as the correct answer if it solved your query. Thanks.

Comment: Ah okay after the explanation I will remark your answer as correct. Thank you very much!